# Does strictly adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle violate encapsulation?

Tags: oop

It seems that if I strictly adhere to the Single Responsibility principle, then I may have to add public getters in order to split functionalities that may change. To me, this seems to violate encapsulation by exposing the objects internal structure.

For example, assume I have a class that represents an uploaded file. In the past I have used methods like toHtml() in order to avoid getters and maintain encapsulation:

```
public class UploadedFile() {
  private String filename;
  private String uri;
  public String toHtml() {
    return <html string>;
 }
```

But I could see where one could argue that, based on SRP, you might want to include getters for filename and uri and generate the html elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, `filename` and `uri` would be properties of your `UploadedFile()` class that it would be illogical to keep hidden, so providing getters for those doesn't violate encapsulation at all, in my opinion.

The encapsulation violation would occur if you made `filename` and `uri` public fields and just accessed them directly.